# Withings API Status Code 2555

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, withings

I'm trying to integrate Withings with a rails apps. I'm using an [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) provider someone wrote called [omniauth-withings](https://github.com/octanner/omniauth-withings). I was able to configure the provider to allow me to visit /auth/withings which redirects to the Withings authorization page. After I allow access, the browser is redirected to the callback url /auth/withings/callback. I have this routed to a controller action that attempts to get the measurement data from Withings using the [simplificator-withings gem](https://github.com/simplificator/simplificator-withings).

```
Withings.consumer_secret = ENV['withings_app_key']
Withings.consumer_key = ENV['withings_app_secret']

auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
user_id = auth_hash.extra.raw_info.body.users.first.id

withings_user = User.authenticate(user_id, auth_hash.credentials.token, auth_hash.credentials.secret)
measurements = withings_user.measurement_groups(:device => Withings::SCALE)
```

The problem happens when I call User.authenticate(), I get this:

```
An unknown error occurred - Status code: 2555
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error with a django app. It turns out I was using the wrong token and secret. I was using the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret returned from step 1 of the authorization process, rather than the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret from step 3. Make sure you are using the values from step 3. The API documentation shows the same values returned from these calls, but they will be different. Hopefully this helps you too.

Comment: The issue was on the first to lines. I was setting the app key to the secret and secret to the app key. Once I corrected this typo it worked.